# Modify a recordset before performing a pivot

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, ado

I have an access database that I am accessing via vbscript from an asp page.  I need to query the database and return a recordset, modify some of the data in the recordset then perform a pivot.  How can I go about performing a pivot on the modified recordset?

I have the recordset being returned and the data modifications being completed but have no idea as to how to now perform the pivot.  The data modifications involve checking each item in the recordset (a schedule request) to see if it spans across a filter date range.  If it does the beginning and/or end times are adjusted and the times for the request recalculated.  Not something that can be accomplished in the SQL query itself.

Comment: Do you mean that you do not know how to write a crosstab query or that there is some error in your crosstab results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some SQL variations have their own PIVOT functionality, I don't know about ACCESS but here is a general pivotting function in vbscript. I user array's in an array here, no vbscript multidimensional array. Let me know if you need such a version.

```
arr = Array(_
  Array(1,2,3),_
  Array(4,5,6)_
)

for each line in arr
  wscript.echo join(line)
next

'1 2 3
'4 5 6

pivotted = pivot(arr)

function pivot(arr)
  dim arr2(), temp()
  redim arr2(ubound(arr(0)))
  for col = 0 to ubound(arr(0))
    redim temp(ubound(arr))
    for row = 0 to ubound(arr)
      temp(row) = arr(row)(col)
    next
    arr2(col) = temp
  next
  pivot = arr2
end function

for each line in pivotted
  wscript.echo join(line)
next

'1 4
'2 5
'3 6
```